# "Explode" model?

Tags: animation, add-on

I am working on an engine model and I would like to have the part "explode" out and back in. Like this.[image]

I have almost a 1,000 parts and I really dont want to animate them manually as I will be doing this for many different models.

Does anyone know of a plug in that can automatically take my groups and animate them in this fashion?

Comment: Please don't include "thank you" in your answers or edits; it could be added as a comment. The answer should contain related information describing what is shown on the screenshot so that info to be accessible for e.g. searching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help but I found someone with a similar question on blenderartists.org [animating an exploded view](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?317430-Questions-about-animating-an-Exploded-View-in-Blender-Cycles).

In order to move several objects away enable [*Manipulate Center Points*](https://www.blender.org/manual/ru/editors/3dview/object/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/manipulate_center_points.html#manipulate-center-points) button in the 3D Viewport header. When scaling or rotating, it will make selected objects change their positions, but not their proportions.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

in 2.8 it is now called *Transform Affect Only > Locations*

to test it, make 2 objects, select these 2 then perform scale it (or hit keyboard 'S' then drag)

[image]

Comment: Using Blender 2.92 and this is still relevant. Thanks